# Is there any way set video and audio permissions in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, audio, next.js, webcam, getusermedia

i want to set permissions when click button. I'd like to this scenario. firstly, method work at first and allow when the button is pressed.

My code :

```
<button
 onClick={requestPermission}
 className=" ring-1 hover:bg-blue-500 transition-all duration-300 active:bg-blue-600 rounded-lg px-4 py-2 text-xl font-semibold text-white bg-blue-700 flex items-center " >
     <span className="mr-4">İzin ver</span>{" "}
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVideoCamera} />
</button>
 // Permissions
  const requestPermission = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("bu func. calisti");

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      });
      webcamRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      setPermissionGranted(true);
    } catch (error) {
      if (!hideQuestion) {
        console.error("Webcam ve mikrofon izni reddedildi:", error);
        toast.warn("Lütfen Webcam İzinlerini Veriniz...");
      }
      setPermissionGranted(false);
    }
  }, [hideQuestion]);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermission();
  }, []);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'video and audio permissions'?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'd like to webcam permissions when user click the button

Answer (score 0):

The only way to set video / audio permissions to the "granted" state is to attempt a call to getUserMedia. This is to defeat cybercreeps. You can't save the state and restore it later from your Javascript code.

Some browsers, but not all (notably not iOS / iPadOS Safari) save the state for each website origin.